# Linux Novice Question: GCC Compiler output

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation

I am a complete novice with Linux. I have Mint on a laptop and have recently been playing around with it.

I wrote a simple C program and saved the file.
Then in the command line I typed

```
gcc -c myfile
```

and out popped a file called a.out. I naively (after years of Windows usage) expected a nice .exe file to appear. I have no idea what to do with this a.out file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Name it with `-o` and skip the `-c`:

```
gcc -Wall -o somefile myfile
```

You should name your sourcefiles with a `.c` extension though.

The typical way of compiling e.g. two source files into an executable:

```
#Compile (the -c) a file, this produces an object file (file1.o and file2.o)

gcc -Wall -c file1.c
gcc -Wall -c file2.c

#Link the object files, and specify the output name as `myapp` instead of the default `a.out`

gcc -o myapp file1.o file2.o
```

You can make this into a single step:

```
gcc -Wall -o myapp file1.c file2.c
```

Or, for your case with a single source file:

```
gcc -Wall -o myapp file.c
```

The `-Wall` part means "enable (almost) all warnings" - this is a habit you should pick up from the start, it'll save you a lot of headaches debugging weird problems later.

The `a.out` name is a leftover from older unixes where it was an executable format. Linkers still name files `a.out` by default, event though they tend to produce `ELF` and not `a.out` format executables now.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear myfile is the name of the source file right? And somefile is the name of the output executable?

Comment: @JJG: Yep. `-o filename` specifies the "output file name". `-c` specifies "just compile, don't link". If you do not specify an output filename, the *compiler* produces a `filename.o` based on `filename.c`, whereas the linker just defaults to `a.out`

Comment: Also `-ansi -pedantic` might be useful if you tend to compile with different compilers. The default language `gcc` compiles for is "GNU-C"; not all compilers compile that language; OTOH, all so-called C compilers can be made (with varying degrees of difficulty) to compile "C". `gcc -ansi -pedantic` behaves very much like a C (ANSI C89 / ISO C90) compiler.

Answer (score 3):

a.out is the executable file.

run it:

```
./a.out
```

Comment: If he passed `-c` it's not executable

Comment: Thanks. But why isnt it given the same name as the source file by default? Also I tried to open it from the desktop with a double click but it couldn't open.

Comment: if he really passed `-c` gcc would have generated myfile.o, not a.out

Comment: @JJG, for that you will need to ask the implementers of gcc :)

Comment: Trent, you are right? I tried both, I forgot which one produced which output. But I was more interested in what this a.out file was.

Comment: This is a bit late, but you should read this: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2003-01/msg01338.html